# Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `closest-side at 0 0` instead of `0 0, closest-side`

Tags: css, sass

I can't figure out what needs to be changed for this error to go away:

> Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like
> `closest-side at 0 0` instead of `0 0, closest-side`.

Here are some examples of the type of gradients in the code base:

```
background: linear-gradient(#f7f7f7, #eee)
background-image: linear-gradient(
 135deg, 
 #8C8862 2.94%, 
 $green-2 2.94%, 
 $green-2 11.76%, 
 #8C8862 11.76%, 
 #8C8862 14.71%, 
 $red-3 14.71%, 
 $red-3 50%, 
 #8C8862 50%, 
 #8C8862 52.94%, 
 $green-2 52.94%, 
 $green-2 61.76%, 
 #8C8862 61.76%, 
 #8C8862 64.71%, 
 $red-3 64.71%, 
 $red-3 100%)
background: linear-gradient( to top, $white 0%, $grey-3 100% )
```

Anyone have any ideas why any of these would throw that error?

Comment: I am not sure those gradient are throwinh erros, `closest-side` is relative to `radial-gradient`, you are not using them somewhere?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am using those, but only in two places:

Comment: ```background-image: radial-gradient(25% 25%, circle, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3))```

Comment: This isn't using closest-side though right?

Answer (score 8):

Try with `background-image: radial-gradient(25% 25% at 0 0, circle, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has incorrect syntax, the proper syntax is:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
```

`linear-gradient` specifies that you are creating a linear gradient.

`to right` defines the direction of the gradient, going from left to right.

`red` and `blue` are the colors of the gradient, where the gradient starts with red and ends with blue. You can also use hex codes.

In your case it is this line:

```css
background: linear-gradient(#f7f7f7, #eee)
```

It needs a direction.